# Kinematics: relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

The question goes like this:

> An aircraft, with velocity 580 km/h, is supposed to follow a straight path in the direction 38,0° in the northeast (measured from the east). The aircraft experiences a northern wind of 72 km/h. In what direction should the aircraft fly? (the answer is an angle).

I've started with naming the angle $\theta$, then the aircraft has a velocity of $580*\cos{\theta}$ in the x-direction and $580*\sin{\theta} - 72$ in the y-direction. Then we can make the equation $\frac{580*\sin\theta-72}{580*\cos\theta} = \frac{580*sin{38°}}{580*\cos{38°}} = \tan{38°}$. But now I'm struggling on finding the solution to the equation ($\theta=\ldots$). I know the answer is 43.6°, and filling this into the equation gives a valid answer.

Comment: you can solve the equation numerically. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: You mix 37 and 38 degrees in what you write. Also are you measuring angles clockwise from the North (customary for navigation) or anti clockwise from the East (mathematical convention)? Obviously these will give different answers. Finally - add a diagram.

Comment: do you know about this standard solution?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Is a "northern" wind the same as a "north" wind, or is it a "to the north" wind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with drawing a diagram and using the sine rule on triangle $ABC$ to find $\theta$ and hence the answer?

[image]

Comment: Sin rule - clever!

Answer (score 0):

This type of vector problem, where the unknowns are the size of one vector and the direction of another, can be greatly simplified by a rotation of axes.  This rotation should be applied to bring the vector whose size is unknown to lie on one of the axes.

In this case, assuming a wind **from** the North, and angles measured counter-clockwise from the positive x-axis, we can achieve the above rotation by simply subtracting 38 degrees from each vector's direction.  The result is the table below:

[image]
The first two columns (V and New Angle) simply give the three vectors (Plane, Air, and Resultant velocity in the **new** rotated coordinates.

The next two columns give the x- and y- components of each vector.  Note that the x and y axes are the rotated ones.  **The effect of the rotation is to remove the unknown $R$ from one of the columns.**

Adding the Plane and Air y-components and setting the sum equal to the y-component of the desired velocity over the ground, we get an equation with one unknown:
$$580 \sin (A) +72 \sin (232)=R \sin(0)=0$$that solves to give $A = 5.61$

Adding 38 to unrotate the axes, we get the heading of the plane is 43.61 degrees.

Answer (score -1):

Wolfram alpha is your friend:

[image]

The screen shot clips some of the conditions and other parts of the solution (which are irrelevant given the inputs)... Basically there is a +/- sign in the solution (which you will recognize as the solution to a quadratic equation... Can you see how to rearrange things into a quadratic?)